# PayPal IPN authentication flow: HTTP or HTTPS?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Reading the documentation at developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN, I see the following picture about the
[PayPal IPN authentication flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgqDV.gif) that I can't attach.

However, the IPN payment notification system of Paypal has recently changed a bit for security reasons: [look here](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1766&expand=true&locale=en_US). And I suspect that the documentation above is not updated accordingly (but maybe I'm just wrong)

With respect to that picture and that PayPal change, I'd like to understand the following:

1) Is the connection in Step 2 now done via HTTP or HTTPS?

2) Is the connection in Step 3 now done via HTTP or HTTPS?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would actually be Step 4.  When your URL POSTs data back to PayPal for verification of the data you will need to make sure you're using https:// on that URL and not just http:// or PayPal won't accept the request at all.

Comment: True. But my question concerns steps 2 and 3... is it necessary for my server to accept SSL connections from the PayPal servers? Or can my server just receive HTTP connection from PayPal server? In the second case, I don't need to neither buy a SSL certificate nor do the subsequent setup!

Comment: Your IPN URL does not need to be protected by SSL (although it would be recommended.)